# UTF-8 text in HDInsight cluster with spark result encoding error 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, encoding, ascii, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

Trying to work with Hebrew characters UTF-8 TSV file in HDInsight cluster with spark on Linux and I get encoding error, any recommendations?

There's my pyspark notebook code:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
# Create an RDD from sample data
transactionsText = sc.textFile("/people.txt")

header = transactionsText.first()

# Create a schema for our data
Entry = Row('id','name','age')

# Parse the data and create a schema
transactionsParts = transactionsText.filter(lambda x:x !=header) .map(lambda l: l.encode('utf-8').split("\t"))
transactions = transactionsParts.map(lambda p: Entry(str(p[0]),str(p[1]),int(p[2])))

# Infer the schema and create a table       
transactionsTable = sqlContext.createDataFrame(transactions)

# SQL can be run over DataFrames that have been registered as a table.
results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM transactionsTempTable")

# The results of SQL queries are RDDs and support all the normal RDD operations.
names = results.map(lambda p: "name: " + p.name)

for name in names.collect():
  print(name)
```

**Error:**

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-11: ordinal not in
>   range(128) Traceback (most recent call last): UnicodeEncodeError:
>   'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-11: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

Hebrew Text file content:

```
id  name    age 
1   גיא 37
2   maor    32 
3   danny   55
```

**When I try English file it works fine:**

English Text file content:

```
id  name    age
1   guy     37
2   maor    32
3   danny   55
```

**Output:**

```
name: guy
name: maor
name: danny
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?  A screenshot of all the output is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the following code with the hebrew text:

```
from pyspark.sql import *

path = "/people.txt"
transactionsText = sc.textFile(path)

header = transactionsText.first()

# Create a schema for our data
Entry = Row('id','name','age')

# Parse the data and create a schema
transactionsParts = transactionsText.filter(lambda x:x !=header).map(lambda l: l.split("\t"))

transactions = transactionsParts.map(lambda p: Entry(unicode(p[0]), unicode(p[1]), unicode(p[2])))

transactions.collect()
```

you'll notice that you get the names as a list of `unicode` type:

```
[Row(id=u'1', name=u'\u05d2\u05d9\u05d0', age=u'37'), Row(id=u'2', name=u'maor', age=u'32 '), Row(id=u'3', name=u'danny', age=u'55')]
```

Now, we'll register a table with the transactions RDD:

```
table_name = "transactionsTempTable"

# Infer the schema and create a table       
transactionsDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(transactions)
transactionsDf.registerTempTable(table_name)

# SQL can be run over DataFrames that have been registered as a table.
results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM {}".format(table_name))

results.collect()
```

You'll notice that all strings in the Pyspark `DataFrame` coming back from `sqlContext.sql(...` will be of Python `unicode` type:

```
[Row(name=u'\u05d2\u05d9\u05d0'), Row(name=u'maor'), Row(name=u'danny')]
```

Now running:

```
%%sql
SELECT * FROM transactionsTempTable
```

Will get the expected result:

```
name: גיא
name: maor
name: danny
```

---

Do note that if you wanted to do some work on those names, you'd want to work with them as `unicode` strings. From [this article](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html):

> When you’re dealing with text manipulations (finding the number of
>   characters in a string or cutting a string on word boundaries) you
>   should be dealing with unicode strings as they abstract characters in
>   a manner that’s appropriate for thinking of them as a sequence of
>   letters that you will see on a page. When dealing with I/O, reading to
>   and from the disk, printing to a terminal, sending something over a
>   network link, etc, you should be dealing with byte str as those
>   devices are going to need to deal with concrete implementations of
>   what bytes represent your abstract characters.

Comment: @guy-bertental, did the answer solve your issue? If so, please accept it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try that as soon as I get back to the office and I'll let you know.

Comment: it works! thank you very much! what if i want now to save my table using dfw = DataFrameWriter(transactionsTable)
dfw.saveAsTable('transactions') and run select query in Hive?

Comment: So my previous code is wrong regarding encodings. I'll update my answer to have the right encodings, and then `%%sql` will work.